# Spring Oauth2 and custom validation.Custom filter is not working

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-oauth2

Let me narrate my problem,

In my spring boot application, there is a requirement to retrieve two token one is the bearer and other is a custom one and authenticate both and logical AND the result.
For this, My idea is to override the doFilter() of OAuth2AuthenticationProcessingFilter and use a custom authentication manager to authenticate both tokens.

For this I just created a custom filter, code snippet is given below

```
@Configuration
public class CustomWebSecurityConfigurerAdapter
  extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.addFilterBefore(new 

CantizOauth2Authenticationfilter(),OAuth2AuthenticationProcessingFilter .class);
    }
}
```

.But while running getting an error like this
Cannot register after unregistered Filter OAuth2AuthenticationProcessingFilter.
Please help to resolve this.

Comment: same problem.  Did you work this out?

Answer (score 0):

Based on the exception looks like you don't have the OAuth2AuthenticationProcessingFilter added to your filter chain.
Try changing OAuth2AuthenticationProcessingFilter.class by UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.class